# File manipulation in PHP: lock, read, clear, unlock

Tags: php, file-io, locking

I want some PHP to do the following in this order:

1. Gain exclusive lock to a file (waiting if already locked)
2. Read the contents of the file
3. Empty the file of all contents
4. Remove the lock

But any code I'm coming up with one way or another always relinquishes the lock between the reading and writing.

```
$fp = fopen('status.txt', 'r+');
flock($fp, LOCK_EX);
$str = fread($fp,1000); // [another hack. I just want it to read everything]
unlink('status.txt');
touch('status.txt');
```

Any ideas? I don't trust anything I do with files.

Answer (score 3):

I think ftruncate can do what you want, since it works on a file that you already have open.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftruncate.php

Here's their example:

```
<?php
$filename = 'lorem_ipsum.txt';

$handle = fopen($filename, 'r+');
ftruncate($handle, rand(1, filesize($filename)));
rewind($handle);
echo fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
?>
```

So I think what you want then is something like:

```
$fp = fopen('status.txt', 'r+');
flock($fp, LOCK_EX);
$str = fread($fp, filesize('status.txt'));
ftruncate($fp, 0);
flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Can you also safely `unlink('status.txt')` after `fclose($fp)`?
According to: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php#Hcom101226